# How can i find next highest value in django query

Tags: python, django

I am using django 1.7.

I have field called `priority`.

I want to find next `high value and previous low value`

for example if i have this in database

`1,5,8,4,12,19,31`

So for example if my current `priority = 12` then i want to get record with `priority 19` and previous with `priority=8`

I  am not able to figure out how to do

Comment: Wouldn't you want to get the records with priority 19 and 8 (instead of 4) ?

Comment: @Mazvél u r right , that was typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the next object, first filter to get all objects with a higher priority:

```
objects = MyObjects.objects.filter(priority__gt=12)
```

then order the results by priority:

```
objects = objects.order_by('priority')
```

finally select the first item in the queryset:

```
next_obj = objects.first()
```

Putting it together:

```
next_obj = MyObjects.objects.filter(priority__gt=12).order_by('priority').first()
```

Getting the previous object is similar, but you need to order in reverse:

```
prev_obj = MyObjects.objects.filter(priority__lt=12).order_by('-priority').first()
```

Note that [`first()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.first) can return `None` if there are no objects in the queryset (in your case, that means the current object has the highest or lowest priority in the list). If the same priority can appear more than once, you might want to adjust the code to use [`gte`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#gte) and [`lte`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#lte).